# Pig Latin - adding values from different bags?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have one file max_rank.txt containing:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

and second file max_rank_add.txt:

```
d
e
f
```

My expecting result is:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c,
4,d,
5,e
6,f
```

So I want to generate `RANK` for second set of values, but starting with value greater than max from first set.

Beginig of the script probably looks like this:

```
existing = LOAD 'max_rank.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (id: int, text : chararray);
new = LOAD 'max_rank_add.txt' using PigStorage() AS (text2 : chararray);
ordered = ORDER existing by id desc;
limited = LIMIT ordered 1;
new_rank = RANK new;
```

But I have problem with last, most importatn line, that adds value from `limited` to `rank_new`  from `new_rank`.

Can you please give any suggestions?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. 
Both scripts work:

```
rank_plus_max = foreach new_rank generate flatten(limited.$0 + rank_new), text2;
rank_plus_max = foreach new_rank generate limited.$0 + rank_new, text2;
```

These DOES NOT work:

```
rank_plus_max = foreach new_rank generate flatten(limited.$0) + flatten(rank_new);

2014-02-24 10:52:39,580 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 10, column 62>  mismatched input '+' expecting SEMI_COLON
Details at logfile: /export/home/pig/pko/pig_1393234166538.log
```